# Chrome Extension: Temporarily swap/stash clipboard contents

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, clipboard, clipboard-interaction

I am in the process of creating a chrome extension that allows you to click on context menu options when you are in an `editable` element. Clicking a context menu option automatically places some text where the cursor is.

---

The problem I am having is that the process for placing the text differs based on where the text is being placed. For example, If the text is being placed in a `textarea`, (like the one I am typing in now), the process is different than if I need to put the text in, say, a YouTube comment box, which is its own custom div and does not support the operations that I would use when editing the contents of a normal `textarea`

---

In my search for a flexible solution that would work the same for all elements that are in the `editable` category of the `chrome.contextMenus` API, I thought of the following Idea:

I should be able to do what I want if I store my variable in the system clipboard with `document.execCommand('copy')` and then paste it in wherever the cursor is with `document.execCommand('paste')`

---

**The downside here is that the user would loose whatever they used to have in their clipboard.**

I originally planned on just pasting the original contents into my own `textarea`, then restoring it once I am done with the clipboard, but there are 2 problems with this approach:

- The user would loose whatever formatting they had originally
- This would only work for text, not images.

**Is there a way that I can save the contents of the clipboard that would allow me to copy them back to the clipboard at later time without the user noticing any modification to the content?**

> If I have any glaring misconceptions, please correct me as I am new to
>   JS, the DOM and HTML

Comment: You already asked that before though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908309/storing-clipboard-data-into-a-variable-with-javascript-and-the-google-chrome-api

Comment: **TL;DR version of the question:** "How to temporarily swap/stash clipboard contents regardless of their format and then put it back"

Comment: @Xan That was a separate question, at that point, I was specifically trying to store the contents into a string variable.  At this point, I am looking for a way to AVOID doing that, because it does not allow me to do what I want.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things a lot by using the clipboard. Why do you need it? There are ways to just insert text programmatically where the cursor is, not just pasting text. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418958/insert-text-in-a-textarea-text-input-at-the-cursor-when-code-is-being-executed?rq=1

Comment: I can try that when i get home, but the main problem I was having last night was that, if you are in, say, a YouTube comment box, document.activeElement.value actually returns undefined. This leads me to believe that the solution you pointed me to does not provide the flexibility I need

Comment: Where do you test it? You need to inject a content script in response to the context menu event and do it _there_.

Comment: That is what i am doing. To be clear I do have a solution that works if you are in a normal text area, but if it is in a custom div, it does not work.     I can post the code I do have later tonight if it would help.

Comment: Problem is, on YT comments are actually sandboxed in an iframe. It's certainly possible to reach there and modify the editable `<div>`, but that's indeed a lot of work and corner cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69251/discussion-between-lukep-and-xan).